# Jquery function need to be combined

Tags: jquery

I am trying to combine these two jQuery functions but not sure how to do it. I am not to familiar with jQuery. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slidingDiv_a").hide();
    $(".show_hide_a").show();

    $('.show_hide_a').click(function(){
        $(".slidingDiv_a").slideToggle();
    });

});

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slidingDiv_b").hide();
    $(".show_hide_b").show();

    $('.show_hide_b').click(function(){
        $(".slidingDiv_b").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

Comment: have you tried copy paste? Just put content of second function into first one

Comment: You have a single function that takes the selectors' suffix and returns the function containing the work for that particular function. Or if you never need them separately, two function calls to a function taking the suffix that does the same work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put everything in one big .ready():

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv_a").hide();
    $(".show_hide_a").show();
    $(".slidingDiv_b").hide();
    $(".show_hide_b").show();

    $('.show_hide_a').click(function(){
       $(".slidingDiv_a").slideToggle();
    });

    $('.show_hide_b').click(function(){
        $(".slidingDiv_b").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: I guess this will work I thought maybe I could use a case or switch to shorten the code because I have to add c and d

Comment: @Donny There are ways to combine, depending on the overall structure of the page. You can assign a class  `show_hide` and then use `$('.show_hide').click()` and in that function you need to figure out through id or parent/child relationship or some other connection which slidingDiv to toggle. If it is only a few items involved then repeating code is often the simplest solution.

Comment: Thank you your right repeating was the easiest.